# $C(X) \cup C(Y) = C(X \cup Y)$ if $C$ is an algebraic closure and $X, Y$ are finite?

Tags: lattice-orders

According to Brris & Sankappanavar's "*A course in universal algebra*," the set $L_C$ of closed subsets of a set $A$ forms an algebraic lattice under $\subseteq$, given that the closure oprator is an algebraic closure operator on $A$.

> Here, a subset $X$ of $A$ is said to be closed if $C(X) = X$, and the closure operator $C$ on $A$ is said to be algebraic if $C$ satisfies C4, on top of C1 - C3, below:
>
> (For any $X, Y \subseteq A$)
> C1: $X \subseteq C(X)$
> C2: $C^2(X) = C(X)$
> C3: $X \subseteq Y \Rightarrow C(X) \subseteq C(Y)$
> C4: $C(X) = \bigcup \{C(Y): Y$ is a finite subset of $X \}$
>
> A lattice $\langle L, \le \rangle$ is called algebraic if it is complete and compactly generated;
> A lattice $\langle L, \le \rangle$ is said to be compactly generated if each of its elements is the supremum of a set of compact elements of $\langle L, \le \rangle$; 
> and an element $a$ of a lattice $\langle L, \le \rangle$ is called a compact element of $\langle L, \le \rangle$ if for each subset $\Delta \subseteq L$ s.t. $a \le sup \Delta$, there is a finite subset $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ s.t. $a \le sup \Gamma$.

B&S' proof that $\langle L_C, \subseteq \rangle$ forms a compactly generated lattice seems to assume the following [1] without explanation (probably because it's obvious for most people):

[1] If $C$ is an algebraic operator on a set $A$ and each of $X$ and $Y$ is a finit subset of $A$, then $C(X) \cup C(Y) = C(X \cup Y)$.

But, I cannot so far show [1].   I will appreciate any help.

Here is how and where I think [1] is assumed:

Let $X$ be an arbitrary subset of $A$, $\Delta = \{ C(Y): Y$ is a finite subset of  $ X \}$.  (And $\Delta ' = \{Y \subseteq A: Y$ is a finite subset of$ X \}$.)  Then, $C(X) = \bigcup \Delta$ by C4.  If I can assume [1], then $\bigcup \Delta = C( \bigcup \Delta ')$, so, $C(X) = C(\bigcup \Delta ')$.   (Or, if I can assume [3] below, $C(X) = C(\bigcup \Delta ')$ immeiately.)  Meanwhile, $C( \bigcup \Delta ') = sup \Delta$ (in $L_C$)  as a property of the complete lattice $L_C$ due to C1-C3.  Thus $C(X) = sup \Delta$.   Since each $C(Y) \in \Delta$ is a compact element of $L_C$ (which is explained in detail in B&S), $C(X)$ is the supremum of a set of compact elements of $L_C$.

---

I have two thoughts.

- If [2] below holds for $X, Y$ of [1], then [1] follows from [2] and C4.

[2] $\{ Z \subseteq X \cup Y: Z$ is finite$ \} = \{ Z \subseteq X: Z$ is finite$ \} \cup \{ Z \subseteq Y: Z$ is finite$ \}$.

But, [2] seems false.

- If [3] below holds in general, then the need of [1] is obviated.

[3] $X = \bigcup \{ Y \subseteq X: Y$ is finite$ \}$
for any subset $X$ of any set $A$.

But, assuming [3] somehow seems epistemologically illicit or something, when $X$ is not finite...

Comment: The _smallest_ closed subset containing $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ is $C(X \cup Y)$. But in general that is not $C(X) \cup C(Y)$.

Comment: Consider the lattice of subgroups of a group. Of course [1] fails then. In general, we only have $C(X \cup Y) = C(C(X) \cup C(Y))$. I am pretty sure that the book you cite doesn't use a wrong result.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you for the reply.  Please correct me if I misinterpret your comment, but I take it as meaning that if the closure operator satisfies only C1 - C3 and the $X$ and $Y$ are given just as any subsets of $A$, then, $sup\{C(X), C(Y) \} = C(X \cup Y)$.  That was my thought, precisely.  So, I wondered that C4 and the $X, Y$ being finite might make [1] true.  I added some detail of why I thought [1] was needed to prove that $L_C$ was a compactly generated lattice, above.  If you could help me to get out of this in any way, I will appreciate it.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for the comment.  If I sounded as if I was suggesting B&S made a mistake, please forgive my poor language. (I'm still learning pragmatic subtleties of English.) Strictly speaking, all I'm convinced now is that the $L_C$ would be a compactly generated lattice if [1] follows from C1-C4, but I have found no reason to think that the proof fails unless [1] follows, as of now.  And, I'm thinking that I'm stuck here probably because I'm missing something. I even worry that Im misunderstanding your comment (and Zhen Lin's). Please help if so.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your suggestion of the counterexample to [1], too.  Actually, I'm not a mathematician or a math major, though I took a course called abstract algebra years ago at a college (for fun) in which I studied a little bit about groups.  I'm now trying to recall what I learned there to understand your counterexample, which is taking time.  Please know that Im not ignoring your hint, but working on it.

Comment: @Martin Thank you very much for the counterexample!  I think I finally verified it.  It was very fascinating to observe this relation between group, closure, and lattice.  I verified that, given a group G, the set-generating operator $\langle - \rangle$ forms an algebraic closure operator on G, and any $a, b \in G$ s.t. $a \notin \langle b \rangle$ and $b \notin \langle a \rangle$ would form a counterexample to $\langle X \cup Y \rangle \subseteq \langle X \rangle \cup \langle Y \rangle$.  (I have found no specific example, though...)   I wish your comment was an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @Martin If you don't mind, I'll post an answer myself (just for the sake of completion), mentioning that the answer was actually fully given by your comment. (The answer will state that [1] is false and, thus, B&S's proof must have used some other reasoning.)

Answer (score 2):

As Martin Brandenburg elegantly explains, your assumption [1] is false, even if the closure operator is algebraic (he gives an example of an algebraic closure operator for which the assumption fails).

Your assumption [2] is also false, unless $X \subseteq Y$ or $Y \subseteq X$.
For otherwise, take $x \in X \setminus Y$ and $y \in Y \setminus X$, and you get $\{x,y\}$, a finite subset of $X \cup Y$ which is neither a subset of $X$ nor a subset of $Y$ (although it is a union of a subset of $X$ with a subset of $Y$; maybe that is the reason of your confusion?).

Your assumption [3] is clearly correct, and that's the one that is used in proving the the theorem.
And no, there is no epistemological illicitude in assuming that an infinite set is the union of its finite subsets.
Actually, any set, of any cardinality, is the union of singletons:
$$X = \bigcup \{ \{x\} : x \in X \}.$$ 
I hope that helps...